# Erlang rotating/random global value

Tags: erlang, load-balancing

I have a cluster of c-nodes that connect to my erlang instance and need to have messages distributed amongst them. My current method of doing this is to have a `-define` of the list of cnode name atoms, and a `gen_server` which simply responds to request for the names by rotating the list and sending back whatever is currently at the front, and the requesting process then interacts with whatever node it was given. Unfortunately these c-nodes are very heavily used and that `gen_server` is backing up significantly (staying at around 2k-6k messages in its queue).

I'm wondering if there's any other way I could "load balance" across these c-nodes. My initial thought was to just pick a random element from the list whenever a process needs to interact with one, but that seems extremely inefficient to me. Are there any other methods I'm not thinking of?

Comment: In my experience random distribution improved performance over round-robin distribution.  Don't give up on random distribution without running and benchmarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few other methods you could try out:

1. **Hashing** - you take a client id or something unique and hash it over the list of down stream servers to pick
2. **Round Robin** - you store all down stream servers in an ets table and keep a last accessed tuple with them. You then grab all servers from the ets table and find the least recently used, updating the field at the same time.
3. **Random** - just pick one.

But I'm going to have to agree with Saurabh Barjatiya.

> **Don't give up on random distribution without running ... benchmarks.**

I had a production system where we tried to do round robin load balancing because I thought that the random partitioning would be too "inefficient" and not "smooth" enough for what we needed.

After working through a few different solutions (ets tables, hashing, gen_server stuff mostly the above three with a few others really embarrassing solutions) i tried the following out **knowing** that it wasn't going to work well enough:

```
Count = length(Targets),
random:seed(now()),
Route = lists:nth(random:uniform(Count),Targets),
```

After testing it out locally, and then in a production system, turned out **it was fast enough** (if not the fastest), and it distributed everything **smooth enough** for what we needed, and we haven't any performance issues because of it.

In general don't make the same mistake I did and waste time <strike>optimizing</strike> complicating code that does not need to be optimized. **Always** benchmark a solution to really see if your assumptions are correct.

Comment: Looking back, that's basically the exact same code we ended up using :)